# PHP PDO not selecting database

Tags: php, pdo, connection-string

I am trying to connect to a database with PHP PDO and i keep getting this: "Error: No database selected".  The code i had before PDO was working just fine.  Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?  I am new to PDO.

Old Code:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbUser = 'username';
$dbPass = 'password';
$dbName = 'database_name';
$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to the database!');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

PDO Code:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'username';
$dbPass = 'password';
$dbName = 'database_name';
$dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=$dbHost;port=3306;dbname=$dbName', $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **DOUBLE QUOTES**

Single quotes do not allow variables in them.

For example:

```
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;port=3306;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Or better as to make sure everything is escaped correctly:

```
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbHost};port=3306;dbname={$dbName}", $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Comment: hmm...tried both ways (dumb mistake on my part with the quotes).  Although, i still get "ERROR: no database selected"

Comment: @ryanpitts1 make sure **all** of your variables are correct ^_^

Comment: Ok, i blame myself for trying to do things too quick and not thinking it through.  I believe it was actually a different piece of the code that was using mysql_query().  I created a blank page with just the above code (with the sprintf - thanks for that suggestion) and all is well.  Thanks for the quick help, sorry to waste anyone's time. ;)

Comment: @ryanpitts1 no problem ^_^ happy to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to Neal's answer using `sprintf` to get your variables out of the strings:

```
$dbconn = new PDO(
    sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $dbHost, $dbName),
    $dbUser,
    $dbPass
)
```

Also to make sure the resulting string is correct you should print it:

```
print sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $dbHost, $dbName);
```

The port *3306* is default for MySQL and not really necessary to specify.